# Yarn install will not fetch from remote repository

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

Whenever I try to run `yarn install` on a react-app I have the following issue when it comes to retrieving from the remote repository:

```
➤ YN0001: │ Error: Decompression failed
    at BrotliDecoder.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:190:17)
    at processChunkSync (node:zlib:459:12)
    at zlibBufferSync (node:zlib:178:12)
    at Object.syncBufferWrapper [as brotliDecompressSync] (node:zlib:794:14)
    at h_.exports.getContent (/Users/X/app/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.0.cjs:198:58091)
    at Object.lTe (/Users/X/app/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.0.cjs:426:3890)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Vs.fetchFromNetwork (/Users/x/app/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.0.cjs:695:23730)
    at async p (/Users/X/app/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.0.cjs:432:1305)
```

I've made sure to delete node_modules before running and removed yarn.lock
I have also experimented with using yarn v4 and it seems to work ok but has a failure when building later on so thought I should persist with yarn 3.1 as specified in the project.